# UnicodeEncodeError error when trying to fetch HTML tags through BeautifulSoup library

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am getting UnicodeEncodeError while trying to execute 'prettify' function from BeautifulSoup library.

Below is the error that occurred:

**UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\u200b' in position 97: character maps to**

Code block that I am trying to execute is below.

```
import urllib2
link = 'https://stackoverflow.com/'
history = urllib2.urlopen(link)

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
ht = BeautifulSoup(history,"html.parser")

print ht.prettify()
```

Comment: If you want to parse stackoverflow then there is api available https://api.stackexchange.com/docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
html = urlopen("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44880061/unicodeencodeerror-error-when-trying-to-fetch-html-tags-through-beautifulsoup-li#44880061")
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html,"lxml")

print (bsObj.prettify().encode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: Just change in line no. 8 worked.

print ht.prettify().encode('utf-8')

Thanks for help.